# How to disable users from admin panel and django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-admin, disable

I know they provide add, update, delete and view. But I want the users' data to not get deleted and disable user so they cannot use website until enabled again.

Answer (score 1):

The django admin provides an `is_active` checkbox. [image]

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck the is_active checkbox and save.
Django does not log in users whose is_active value is False.